# Does Edgar Markov's Eminence ability trigger with Maskwood Nexus?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I was playing with an [Edgar Markov](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Edgar%20Markov) deck and a question came up: would using [Maskwood Nexus](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Maskwood%20Nexus)' tap ability:

> 3, {T}: Create a 2/2 blue Shapeshifter creature token with changeling *(It is every creature type)*

trigger Edgar's Eminence ability:

> Whenever you cast another Vampire spell, if Edgar Markov is in the command zone or on the battlefield, create a 1/1 black Vampire creature token.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, because you have not cast a spell. Activating an ability to create a token is a different game action.

Comment: If it said "Whenever a Vampire enters the battlefield", however, then it would trigger.

Comment: True. But it doesn't - if nothing else because doing so would create an infinite loop as each token triggers another one.

Comment: To be super clear, "casting a spell" means playing a spell card from your hand by paying its mana cost.

Comment: @JamesFaix that is one, but not the only, way to cast a spell - e.g. casting your commander from the command zone is still casting a spell, even though the card does not start in your hand. Many other ways exists as well (flashback, etc).

Comment: @JamesFaix Nope, ‘casting a spell’ means doing something that the rules define as casting a spell (that is seriously the only sane way to describe it). Mostly covered by rule 601, but also by a huge number of other rules (off the top of my head, 702.34, 702.62, 702.81, 702.86, 702.88, and 903.8, but I’m sure there are others), as well as some cards that just let you cast things from other places under special circumstances (for example, [Panglacial Wurm](https://scryfall.com/card/csp/116/panglacial-wurm), or the various cards with Hideaway).

Comment: Ok that's fair. I think my comment is a good first approximation for someone who is unsure of the difference between casting a spell vs a token entering the battlefield. A lot of the edge cases like flashback or madness also mention casting in their reminder text.

Comment: Rule 601 applies to every possible way of casting a spell. You could fully define "casting a spell" as "taking the actions described in rule 601". There are a variety of rules and abilities that grant specific permissions to cast spells, with the primary ones being the first rule in each subsection in the 300 section, and other uncommon permissions granted by the other cited rules.